# Is it possible to reform the method of downvoting?

Tags: feature-request, voting

I was just downvoted for no apparent reason and I have just about had it with PSE. When I vote to close a post, my name becomes public to a lot of people and, in most instances, I have to give a reason for my choice. I don’t see why downvoters are not required to do the same, and I would like to see such a requirement in place.

Comment: My guess is, such a change would have to be implemented across the whole SE site, and is not something PhilosophySE could do on its own. It happens a lot, and it's annoying, but it's one of those things you have to get used to.

Comment: I'm quite certain that any proposal along these lines [will not happen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325416/275243).

Comment: It's a great idea, but substantial changes to process are unlikely to happen.

Comment: You guys should check out Codidact. They’re trying to build their own version of Stack Exchange. Now is the time to get involved since you can influence decisions about what the site will be like this early in the game. We are having more productive conversations over there about major redesigning of QA site features like voting protocols, governance protocols, etc. https://codidact.com/

Comment: I think it would be severely difficult to change any stack exchange policies right now. It took a gigantic strike recently just to get stack exchange to change a policy on AI-banning-banning (yes: banning the banning of AI).

Comment: I wrote a site proposal here, you guys should join and we can work on launching a new site over there with different policies. Codidact is supposed to be more open source and I believe more “community-driven”/democratic. (But it’s still being built, but it needs contributors.) https://proposals.codidact.com/posts/290730